# Avisynth Audio Balance

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, audio-conversion, virtualdub, avisynth

I am hoping someone knows of an easy way to adjust the balance of audio channels in Avisynth.

I’m trying to combine these [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDorTBEhEtk) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihv4f7VMeJw) into one (yes, I know that some already exist). I threw together an Avisynth script (below) to combine them, and it works great, but as an extra touch of detail, I want to adjust the audio balance so that the audio from each video is slightly offset to the corresponding channel (northern hemisphere slightly more from the left, southern slightly more from the right).

Unfortunately, I am having a hard time finding any information about adjusting audio/channel balance in Avisynth, FFMpegSource, or VirtualDub. I would rather avoid having to resort to a full NLE.

Is there an easy way to adjust the audio balance?

```
LoadPlugin("ffms2.dll")

a1 = FFAudioSource("The Truth About Toilet Swirl - Northern Hemisphere.mp4")
a2 = FFAudioSource("The Truth About Toilet Swirl - Southern Hemisphere.mp4")

v1 = FFVideoSource("The Truth About Toilet Swirl - Northern Hemisphere.mp4")
v2 = FFVideoSource("The Truth About Toilet Swirl - Southern Hemisphere.mp4")
v2 = v2.trim(0,-1).loop(2)+v2 # To sync them perfectly

return AudioDub(StackHorizontal(v1, v2), MixAudio(a1, a2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pan filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) in `ffmpeg`. Assuming you have two separate audio streams that are both stereo and you want one stereo output that is a combination of both inputs.

This example will weight the first stereo input to the left, and the second stereo input to the right.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avs -filter_complex \
"[0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge, pan=stereo| FL< 0.6*c0 + 0.4*c2 | FR< 0.4*c1 + 0.6*c3" \
output
```

The [amerge filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) is used to combine the two stereo inputs into one 4 channel input for pan because pan only accepts one input stream.

Comment: That did it. I had to replace `MixAudio` with `MergeChannels` in my Avisynth script since Avisynth can’t output multiple audio streams, and I removed the `amerge` filter from the ffmpeg switches since it was being merged in the script. Then the only trick was trying to find a perfect balance that demonstrates the effect without becoming to awkward. (I really like this version of the merged video; it feels more natural, like like Destin is actually to the left of the viewer and Derek to the right.) Thanks!

Comment: @Synetech Good to hear it worked for you and thanks for fixing the typos. I did test it, and noticed the `Syntax error`, but forgot to actually fix the answer. Feel free to edit the answer to your exact solution if you feel like it.

Comment: (The output can be listed before the other switches as long as it’s after the input. I put it before the filter for readability and size, but either will work; it’s just a matter of taste.)

Comment: @Synetech Although I'm surprised it works for you most of the time `ffmpeg` will ignore trailing options (I've never tried `-filter_complex` as a trailing option). Option placement is important with `ffmpeg` and it is good practice to follow the specified [option placement](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis).

Comment: I guess it was luck from the build I used. FFmpeg is a mess with the many different, incompatible builds. Thanks for the advice.